# On Save button how to retrieve Item template of GridTableView

Tags: radgrid, itemtemplate

I required to get the label value on save button click. as shown in the below code.

```
  <telerik:RadGrid ID ="SettingsGrid" ... />
            <mastertableview ... />
                <DetailTables>
                    <telerik:GridTableView ... />
                       <columns>
                         <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                           <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:Label ID="lbl" Text='<%#Eval("ID")%>' />
```

But i am not getting how to write the foreach loop inside my Save button click to get the label value.

I tried-

```
 foreach(GridDataItem item in rgScopeOfWork.masterTableView.Items)
```

But it gives the values which are outside of the GridTableView. Help me to get the label value which is inside my GridTableView.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get an answer on this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here i found the answer to get the value of GridDetailView on Save buttton click](http://www.telerik.com/forums/get-specific-column-for-every-row-in-details-tables)